# How do const references as return values work in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am learning C++ again after a while and have a problem understanding `const` references as return values. So here is what I've got: a class, `Foo`, which holds a `std::list` as member:

```
class Foo
{
    std::list<int> mList;
    Foo() { mList.insert(mList.end(), { 1, 2, 3 }); }
    size_t size() const { return mList.size(); }
};
```

Creating a `foo` object from class `Foo` and calling `foo.size()` returns 3, which is fine. Now I want to retrieve this list `mList`, with two requirements:

- I don't want to allow the caller to modify the original list; and
- I don't want to create a copy of each list member when retrieving the list.

So after reading a bit on this topic I decided to return a `const` reference to the list. Thus I added the following method to `Foo`:

```
const std::list<int>& getList() const { return mList; }
```

What I expected was that this would return a reference to the list `mList`, so that I can access the original data within this list. But since it's a `const` reference, I also expected that I would not be able to modify the returned list/reference.

However, playing with this a bit I found out the following:

```
Foo foo;
cout << foo.size() << endl;  // returns 3
std::list<int> l = foo.getList();
l.clear();
cout << foo.size() << endl;  // returns 3 again
```

Now this surprises me and leeds me to two questions:

1. Since the 2nd `cout` returns 3 again, the call to `clear()` obviously does not modify the original `foo.mList` object. But why is that the case if I returned a reference? Is there a copy happening during the return?
2. Why am I allowed to call `l.clear()` in the first place, if I have received a `const` (!) reference?

Comment: You need to declare the l variable as a reference.  Otherwise it's just a copy.

Comment: `std::list<int> l = foo.getList();` makes a copy of the list. `const std::list<int>& l = foo.getList();` gets a const reference to the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getList` returns a `const&` to the list.

One thing you can do, if you choose, with a `const&` to a list is copy it.

```
std::list<int> l = foo.getList();
```

here you choose to copy it.  See the `std::list<int> l`?  That isn't a reference.  That is an object.

By assigning the `const&` to it, you said "please copy the contents of the list into my local variable".

This local variable can be cleared, edited, modified, etc.

If you want something that cannot be easily treated like a value, you can write a view type.

```
template<class It>
struct range_view_t {
  It b; It e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
};
template<class C,
  class It = decltype( std::begin( std::declval<C&>() ) )
>
range_view_t<It> range_view( C& c ) {
  return {std::begin(c), std::end(c)};
}
```

Now a `range_view( some_list )` returns an iterable range over the list.

```
template<class X>
X const& as_const( X& x ) { return x; }
```

lets you ensure the range is const:

```
auto r = range_view( as_const( list ) );
```

gives you a read-only range of iterators into the list.

```
template<class C>
using range_over = decltype( range_view( std::declval<C&>() ) );
template<class C>
using const_range_over = range_over<const C>;

class Foo
{
  std::list<int> mList;
  Foo() { mList.insert(mList.end(), { 1, 2, 3 }); }
  size_t size() const { return mList.size(); }
  const_range_over<std::list<int>>
  get_list() const {
    return range_view( mList );
  }
};
```

now `get_list` returns a range view at the `mList` that can be used in a `for(:)` loop.  Storing a copy of the return value of `get_list` won't copy anything, as you are just copying a view of something.

Almost always `auto` is useful here, because the type of the range view is uninteresting to the user.

```
auto l = foo.get_list();
```

`l` has no `.clear()` method.  You can do this:

```
for( auto&& x : l )
  std::cout << x << "\n";
```

however.

Finally, note that `std::list` is almost always the wrong solution to any problem you can describe.

Comment: Disagree with the last statement. It is not uncommon to use a container where inserts in the middle to not invalidate references.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I will accept that as an answer, however, why is a `std::list` _almost always_ the wrong solution? I intend to insert and remove members into/from the list quite often, and I don't need to access members at a certain index. Isn't that the use case for a linked list?

Comment: @matt nope.  Traversal (to find the items) is so slow with a `std::list` it kills any advantage.  If you do not need pointer stability and you add to the end a `std::vector` where you use erase-remove idiom to do a traversal-delete will be ridiculously faster.  There are cases where list is the right answer, but the depend on persistant iterators/pointers/references more than deleting/adding in the middle performance.

Answer (score 4):

When you do `std::list<int> l = foo.getList();`, you create a new list `l` by copying the returned reference (even if `getList()` returns a `const` reference, it's not forbidden to copy it if you want to). So it's later allowed to modify this copy you made.

If you do `const std::list<int>& l = foo.getList();` then no copy is made and `l` remains a `const` reference to an object you cannot modify.